# website open delay in mobile application

Tags: javascript, android, ios, visual-studio, ionic-framework

i am trying to convert my website to a mobile application, i just need from the application to open my website nothing more.

i am using visual studio 2015 using ionic

the website takes about 17 seconds to open, i don't know why, and another thing is that the ***alert*** in case there is no internet is not appearing.

this is my code:
**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {



//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use the Codova API
        if (navigator.onLine)
            window.location = "http://mywebsite.com";
           // toast.show("Welcome to mywebsite,connect to internet to see our products");
        else
            navigator.notification.alert(
     'please connect to internet!',  // message
     alertDismissed,         // callback
     '',            // title
     'Done'                  // buttonName
 );

    }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if (cordova.platformId === "ios" && window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

            // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
            // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
            // a much nicer keyboard experience.
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if(window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }




    });
})
```

Comment: it depends on your device , Test your website in your phone web browser

Comment: @Bigoloo it opens normally when opening it from any browser